# apply css style to a div that contains an errror message

Tags: jquery

The problem is that the jQuery is detecting any error message present on the page.

**see the example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/99tDR/6/)

-and I don't want the style to apply when there is no message.

code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   if($('.CP_CF_Container > span.msg-error').length){   
       $('.vertical-input').addClass('checkbox-fld-error')
   }
});
```

css:

```
.checkbox-fld-error{border:1px solid red}
.CP_CF_Container{width:50%;background-color:#eee;padding:5px;}
.msg-error{color:red}
```

HTML:

```
    <div class="CP_CF_Container">
        <div class="vertical-input">hello there</div>
        <span class="msg-error" >Error</span>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="CP_CF_Container">
        <div class="vertical-input">hello there</div>
        <span class="msg-error" >Error</span>
    </div>
    <br>

    <div class="CP_CF_Container">
        <div class="vertical-input">hello there</div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chain the methods and use the `.prev()` or `.siblings()` method:

```
$('.CP_CF_Container > span.msg-error')
        .prev('.vertical-input')
        .addClass('checkbox-fld-error');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HL9GP/

You can also use the `.has()` method which returns/filters the elements that has the specified element:

```
$('.CP_CF_Container').has('span.msg-error')
                     .find('.vertical-input')
                     .addClass('checkbox-fld-error');
```

Answer (score 1):

Your jQuery on the page was a bit malformed:

Change:

```
if($(this).('.CP_CF_Container > span.msg-error').length){
```

to

```
if($('.CP_CF_Container > span.msg-error').length){
```

http://jsfiddle.net/99tDR/5/

Comment: there was a problem what was really happening was here http://jsfiddle.net/99tDR/6/ and I was trying to not have the class apply when there is no error